# Calculate polygon area javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to calculate the area of a polygon giving some coordinates that can be negative.
When I pass only negative coordinates it gives me a negative area, when I pass only positives it gives me a positive but when I give it a mix ([-1, 0],[-1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 0]) it always give me a negative.

My code is:

```
function calculateArea(coords) {
area = 0;
points = coords.length;
j = points - 1;

for (i = 0; i < points; i++) {
    area += (coords[i][0] + coords[j][0]) * (coords[i][1] - coords[j][1])
    j = i;
}

return area / 2;
}
```

coords is an array of [x,y] coordinates.

The thing is, I'm not completely sure but I think that if I return the absolute value of the area calculated this should be correct.
Am I missing something or returning the absolute should be ok?

Comment: your Y coordinates on the example are never negative, so the area must be positive. If all the Y coordinates are negative, then the are must be negative (integral of -1 from 0 to 1, is -1)

Comment: Where did you get the algotrithm from? It looks very strange..

Comment: Not related to your question, but it's a good practice avoid creating globals in JavaScript. You're creating globals when you do `j = points - 1` and `i = 0`.

Comment: Area sign depends on z-axis orientation you choose. Since you have enumerated vertices clockwise it must be negative. Always. The fact that your formula gives positive values means it is incorrect. It should be a half sum of `x_i*y_(i+1) - x_(i+1)*y_i`

Comment: When I look at the Wikipedia article for polygon, the line that adds areas should be `area += (coords[i][0] * coords[j][1]) - (coords[j][0] * coords[i][1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Area sign depends on how you order vertices not on if some coordinates are negative.

- Clockwise ordering gives negative areas
- Counterclockwise - positive

Assuming you have correct formula itself you could simple use `Math.abs` to always get positive values.

```js
function calculateArea(coords) {
  let area = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    const [x1, y1] = coords[i];
    const [x2, y2] = coords[(i + 1) % coords.length];

    area += x1 * y2 - x2 * y1
  }

  return area / 2;
  // replace with
  // return Math.abs(area) / 2;
}

console.log('Clockwise:', calculateArea([
  [-1, 0],
  [-1, 1],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 0]
]))

console.log('Counterclockwise:', calculateArea([
  [-1, 0],
  [-1, 1],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 0]
].reverse()))
```